# CS50W lecture7 testing,CI/CD--a problem about YAML and GitHub Actions

Tags: python, django, yaml, github-actions, cs50

I am taking CS50’s Web Programming with Python and JavaScript(CS50W) course. I am now having a problem for [lecture 7 Testing, CI/CD](https://cs50.harvard.edu/web/2020/weeks/7/). When I followed along Brian in the GitHub Actions section(Timestamp at about 1:13:36), the result in my GitHub Actions turned out not to be the same with his.

This is the yaml code( I exactly copied from the lecture) :

```
name: Testing
on: push

jobs:
test_project:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Run Django unit tests
  run:
    pip3 install --user django
    python manage.py test
```

In his GitHub Actions there was nothing wrong about the "run django unit tests" part. But Mine turned out to have some errors. My result in GitHub Actions showed as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxseg.png)(Click to see the screenshot):

```
Run pip3 install --user django python manage.py test
pip3 install --user django python manage.py test
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Collecting django
Downloading Django-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python (from versions: 
none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

So I thought there was something wrong for setting up django or python in the GitHub Ubuntu virtual machine, then I tried to get rid of the `python manage.py test` syntax in the yaml file, and the "run django unit tests" in GitHub Actions turned out no errors. The result showed [as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i3s4.png)(Click to see the screenshot)

```
Run pip3 install --user django
pip3 install --user django
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Collecting django
Downloading Django-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.4.1
Downloading asgiref-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting backports.zoneinfo; python_version < "3.9"
Downloading backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (74 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
Downloading sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Installing collected packages: asgiref, backports.zoneinfo, sqlparse, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.5.0 backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1 django-4.0.3 sqlparse- 
0.4.2
```

It seems django was successfully installed. But what went wrong when the `python manage.py test` syntax was added in the yaml file? I completely have no idea. Can someone point it out? Thanks a lot! You might wanna have a look at [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/BrunoHeZenghui/cs50_airline) for this. If your need more infomation please just tell me. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you were getting indicates that it tried to install python in:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python
```

but python refers to your second command, `python manage.py test`

So the error message indicates that it is trying to run two commands as one single command.

When running multiple commands, you have to include the  `|`  character, so Github Actions understands that there are multiple commands to be run. In the lecture you can see that Brian included the necessary `|` character:

```
run: |
  pip3 install --user django
  python manage.py test
```